# Prove the relation of curves

Tags: calculus, curves

Let $\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)$ a curve, $\overrightarrow{v}(t)$ the vector velocity, and $\overrightarrow{a}(t)$ thre acceleration. We suppose that $\overrightarrow{F}$ is a vector function $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which is $C^1$, $m>0$ and $\overrightarrow{F}(\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t))=m\overrightarrow{a}(t)$. Prove that $$\frac{d}{dt}[m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)\times \overrightarrow{v}(t)]=\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)\times \overrightarrow{F}(\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t))$$

Could you give me some hints how we could prove this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

$$\frac{d}{dt}[m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)\times \overrightarrow{v}(t)]=\frac{d}{dt}[m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)]\times \overrightarrow{v}(t)+m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)\times \frac{d}{dt}[\overrightarrow{v}(t)].$$

Now,

$$\frac{d}{dt}[m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)]\times \overrightarrow{v}(t)=\vec{0}$$ and

$$m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)\times \frac{d}{dt}[\overrightarrow{v}(t)]=m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)\times \overrightarrow{a}(t)=\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)\times \overrightarrow m{a}(t).$$ Thus, we are done.

Comment: Could you explain to me why the following stands?? $$\frac{d}{dt}[m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)]\times \overrightarrow{v}(t)=\vec{0}$$ @mfl

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{\sigma}(t)=\vec{v}(t).$ Thus $\frac{d}{dt}[m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)]\times \overrightarrow{v}(t)=m\vec{v}(t)\times \vec{v}(t)=\vec{0}.$

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!!! :-) 

$$$$ 

At this exercise there is also asked to what we cocnlude if $\overrightarrow{F}(\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t))$ and $\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)$ are parallel. What does it stand in that case?? That $$\frac{d}{dt}[m\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)\times \overrightarrow{v}(t)]=0$$ ?? @mfl

Comment: Yes. If $\overrightarrow{F}(\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t))$ and $\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)$ are parallel then $\overrightarrow{F}(\overrightarrow{\sigma}(t))\times \overrightarrow{\sigma}(t)=\vec{0}.$ Thus, what you have said is the correct conclussion.

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!!! :-)